# Simple GeoJSON transformation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, leaflet, postgis

I'm using leaflet.js to render several geometries based around natural features.  The base geometries can be a simple disk or as complex as a perimeter that follows a large treeline.  I'm storing these in postgres and using postGIS functions to calculate variations on them.

The geometries are also being expanded to GeoJSON before being sent to the client via an ajax request.  Some of the results are very large, so I'd like to be able to do some of the work on the client side.

I would like to do some simple calculations, given the base geometry, which would produce a new geometry representing an expansion of the original - showing, say, 3 or 4 miles distance around it.  This would keep me from having to send additional geometries from server to client.  This function would need to take into account multiple, disconnected polygons where the expanded perimeter would surround all of them.

I'm starting to look at things like https://github.com/cschwarz/wkx, d3, and openLayers.  I may use the library for more than just the above in the future, but I don't really need a lot other than this right now.  I'm hoping someone knows of a straightforward, simple to implement way of doing basic postGIS-like calculations in JS.

I'm using node, browserify and need to support IE9+, FF, Chrome and Safari.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar enough with PostGIS formats to offer a solution to your first problem, but for your second problem, once you have the data as GeoJSON, [turf.js](http://turfjs.org/) will do [buffering](http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_buffer.html) as well as many other basic GIS operations.

Comment: I edited my question to remove the first problem so that it's more concise.  turf.js may be exactly what I'm looking for.  Thanks!